# ASP.NET Web Forms User Registration Email Confirmation, IdentityHelper does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Following the tutorial [Create a secure ASP.NET Web Forms app with user registration, email confirmation and password reset (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/security/create-a-secure-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-user-registration-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) I get to the section '**Enable Email Confirmation**' however, on the line 'string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);' 'IdentityHelper' doesn't exist and I can't proceed.

Quick action recommends using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client however this contains nothing for 'GetUserConfirmationRedirectURL' so this isn't really helpful.

I've searched online for alternative tutorials however have found nothing helpful for ASP.NET Web Forms.

```
    protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = reg_UserName.Text, Email = reg_Email.Text };

        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
            string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
            manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");

            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            StatusMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

}

"The name 'IdentityHelper' does not exists in the current context".

Is IdentityHelper just no longer supported?

Thanks in advance for reading and hope you can help.

Comment: Sorry guys, I can't post images as I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: When you create the project with at least v4.5, there is a WebFormsPA.IdentityHelper . In the Model Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image of my static class IdentityHelper

[image]